# Views will display entities the user does not have "view" access permission

Tags: 8, views

I have a custom entity type that can be viewed by certain people only. This works just fine, when people go to "mysite.com/custom-entity/8" some can see the info, some get "access denied" error.

The problem is I created a view to display a list of those entities and all of them are shown to all users, even if certain users shouldn't have "view" access permission.

LE: Caching is set to "None"

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like it could be a caching issue. Does this happen without caching enabled for your view?

Comment: Caching is set to "None"

Comment: Is the access on the custom entity controlled by a configurable permission?

Comment: Access is controlled by a custom access control handler just like any other Drupal entity.

Comment: Gotcha. When you create a custom entity in Drupal you can define a permission for viewing the entity which will be managed through the standard configuration system. The benefit to that is exactly what I have outlined in my answer below: you can tie that permission to other operations on the site that you cannot affect within an access control handler.

Comment: I updated my answer :)

Comment: It has nothing to do with view access handler, all users should have access to the view but the view results should be different per user. Eg: UserX should see a list of entities like e1, e2, e3 and UserY should see only e1 and e2.

Answer (score -1):

**Option A**

Create a custom access handler for your view.

[Drupal 8 - Views Custom Access with a Plugin](https://badzilla.co.uk/drupal-8-views-custom-access-plugin) is a great guide. It seems like your scenario may fit the use case outlined in the beginning:

"... prohibit the display of a Drupal 8 View dependent upon some custom rules that don't fit easily with Drupal's permissions model ..."

*Pro:* You will get exactly the control features you want.

*Con:* A lot of custom code.

**Option B**

If you want permission for viewing the entity to be directly tied to the view access, there is an "Access" section on the view configuration form. Select "Permission" and then select the permission for viewing the entity you have created.

*Pro:* Easy to set up.

*Con:* Your use case must fit into Drupal's permissions system.